# disable refreshing iframe while sorting

Tags: tinymce, jquery-ui-sortable

I have list of textareas. For textareas I use tinyMCE Editor. When I start sorting this list of textareas, inside these textareas everything disappears. I mean the iframes do not refresh their content.

```
<ul id="sortable">
<li class="ui-state-default"><br />
    <textarea id="1"></textarea>
</li>
<li class="ui-state-default"><br />
    <textarea name="2" id="2"></textarea>
</li></ul>
```

my.js file

```
    tinyMCE.init({
    mode : 'textareas',
    theme : 'advanced',
    theme_advanced_buttons1 : 'save,newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect',
    theme_advanced_buttons2 : '',
    theme_advanced_buttons3 : '',       
    theme_advanced_toolbar_location : 'top',
    theme_advanced_toolbar_align : 'left',
    theme_advanced_statusbar_location : 'bottom',
    theme_advanced_resizing : false
});
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable({

    });
```

TinyMCE works perfect till I drag the <li> where this textarea is placed. Code inside <iframe> disappeared.
Can I somehow prevent refreshing the iframe content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem here is that you cannot move the editor in the dom easily.
The solution is to first shut down the tinymce instance (id needed!)

```
tinymce.execCommand('mceRemoveControl',true,'editor_id');
```

then do the DOM action and reinit the tinymce instance

```
tinymce.execCommand('mceAddControl',true,'editor_id');
```

Comment: @Thariama, I have implemented your solution at: http://cmzmedia.com/tinymce/examples/jquery.html but it seems to not remove the control on drag and then add an extra row of controls on drop. 'editor_id' in my case has been replaced with the ID of the SPAN that the TinyMCE plugin puts in in place of the TEXTAREA. So, after drop the editor replaces itself with a new editor inside of it. Can you edit my code to fix the problem? This is related to my current unsolved issue at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14866630/preserve-content-within-iframe-after-drag-and-drop-tinymce

Comment: Okay, it works when I hard code an id in for one of the TEXTAREA's, but I don't know how to change 'editor_id' in your example to know the ID of TEXTAREA in the row that is being dragged.

Comment: Tinymce takes your textarea id and uses it as the id for the editor (dafualt is "content" if no id is avialable). It is crucial to use unique ids with several editors, otherwise the initialization will fail. you can get the available editor ids using tinymce.editors (this datastructure is an array holding all editorids of the editors currently initialized)