# Preserve content within iframe after drag and drop - TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, tinymce

I am trying to work TinyMCE into a large professional project I am working on. In one spot we need to have multiple instances in table rows that are draggable. However, when you begin dragging one of the rows the content that is in the TinyMCE iFrame (whether it was loaded with the page or altered by the user) disappears. Once you drop the row the content is still gone but re-appears upon page refresh/reload. Is there a way to get the TinyMCE iFrame to preserve its content without needing to do a page reload? I have an example here:

http://cmzmedia.com/tinymce/examples/simple.html

I can't do it in something like jsfiddle because if you do it there and refresh the page it starts everything back from the beginning again.

Or perhaps there is a way to do it where only the dragged-and-dropped iframe is reloaded?

Comment: with FF18 the tinymce content drag-from iframe keeps its content

Comment: Hmm, wonder why it's working for you and not for me.

Answer (score 1):

Since the editor is being re-rendered on a drag and drop, I think you should set the content manually yourself.

You should first grab the contents of the editor being dragged and then restore it after the drop.

To get access to a specific editor you can use `TinyMCE.get('myiframe')`, and then there should be a `getContent` and `setContent` function on that returning editor object to gain access to the editors content.

Comment: Even though I have TinyMCE installed and it is working properly my page throws errors over the .get method you mention (in Firefox), or over .getContent in Chrome. The line I am trying is:

alert(tinyMCE.get('interventionTipOptionItem2').getContent());

Comment: OK, try `tinyMCE.editors["interventionTipOptionItem2"].getContent()` instead.

Comment: Wish I could PM you to talk about this more so I could see how you are getting it to work.

Comment: looks liek you will need to add a drag hnadler to the editor iframe body and get the editor content using ed.getContent() then save it in a variable and write it back when the drop has occured (might be in another frame!)

Comment: I just realized I always use textareas instead of iframes, maybe that's something you can try?

Comment: It's not me using iframes. It's the plugin that uses iframes masked over a textarea.